# How do I place a picture in a post?

Tags: discussion

What is the syntax for placing a picture in a post?

Presumably I would need a link to picture; say its on Wikipedia - how would I discover this...I appreciate though, this bit is not SE specific.

Comment: I think maybe you're supposed to use the manual image import tool, so that SE can host the images on their CDN?

Comment: @weissman: that's sounds more like a tool for developers! Surely there are ways to link a picture already online, after all that's what the nets about; may I ask what is a CDN - Central (something) Network?

Comment: You can provide a custom URL in the import tool dialog (which is the little picture of mountains and a sun at the right of the second group of icons in the editing tools tray.)

Comment: CDN = content delivery network (in this case i think imgur)